# Android multithread preloaded imageview (uri)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-layout

I have written a simple program to display images in a listview but when i scrolling the list , it is very slow.
I want to create a new Thread to handle the loading of imageview.
I read in the forum and in documentation, but I could not understand, **you could write simple code on a separate thread, perhaps with asyntask, to manage what** (preload image in separate thread and show only when is loaded)?
(I plan to not use Picasso or other)

Now in my code, when i press on menu item, i add a imageview(uri) to linearlayout.
Here my code:

***MainActivity:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



ImageView image;
LinearLayout background;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    background=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);


    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {


        //open gallery
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        i.setType("image/* video/*");
         startActivityForResult(i, 0);





         return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Here we need to check if the activity that was triggers was the Image Gallery.
    // If it is the requestCode will match the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS value.
    // If the resultCode is RESULT_OK and there is some data we know that an image was picked
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        // Get the real path from the Uri
        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver  
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();



        image=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());

        image.setImageURI(selectedImage);


        background.addView(image);



    }

}
}
```

***activity_main.xml :***

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.provathreadimmagini.MainActivity" >

              <ScrollView
                 android:id="@+id/s"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                  android:fillViewport="true"
                     >

                 <LinearLayout
                     android:id="@+id/ll"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:gravity="center"
                     android:orientation="vertical"
                      android:paddingBottom="20dp"  >



                 </LinearLayout>
             </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**thank you**

Answer (score 0):

> The idea is that the UI thread (main thread of the application) will
>   not get stuck waiting every time you want to access your files and
>   search for a specific image in order to load it.
>
> For this case you can use (for example) an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
>
> AsyncTask allow you to perform background operations (on a background
>   thread) that will not cause your UI thread freezing.

As you can see in documentation, you should create a class that extends AsyncTask:

```
// In this example first param (URL) indicates the parameter you want to pass. 
// The second param is the progress unit you want to publish while it is computing
// The third is the result you wish yo send to the UI thread
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

}
```

Now, you have to override at least one method:

```
// Long, URL - as stated above
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

}
```

In order to complete this you might want to extend the result function

```
// In this function you should call your UI thread to set the image 
protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

For your example, I would recommend you to move your onActivityResult code into the new doInBackground method.

EDIT:

In your main activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    BackgroundTask task = new BackgroundTask(mImage);
    task.execute(data.getData());
```

In BackgroundTask class:

```
protected Long doInBackground(Uri... uris) {
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uris[0],
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    mImage.setImageURI(uris[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know how works asyntask but I can not be implemented so that the thread loading images,can you write some code?

Comment: thank you very mutch, but the linearlayout scroll lag too, why?

Comment: four..but I would be able to add as many as I would like without lag

Comment: maybe the image size is very large

Comment: It could be a problem (especially when you resize large image) but when you finish loading all images, is it still lagging?

Comment: when i scroll down/up and in the view there is a large image yes, but the loading is in     mImage.setImageURI(uris[0])?

Comment: Yes indeed, at this point it will try to fit the real image size (probably full-hd because it is from the photo library) into the imageview size (which is not described so I can guess it might be _wrap_content_ so you will see fhd image size